# Rails - Externalise Validators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rspec

In my ruby classes I noticed that there are several validators that are repeated such as the validator that checks for the presence of `Id`...
I would like to gather these validators in a external class/module/file and then do something like

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  validates_with :MyCustomExternalValidator
```

Is this possible?

Details:
-Latest Ruby
-RSPEC for testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. From [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html):

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless record.name.starts_with? 'X'
      record.errors[:name] << 'Need a name starting with X please!'
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with MyValidator
end
```

Comment: can i use validators such as "validates_presence_of" or i have to include it on the validate function?

Comment: Yes, you can. This validators present in `ActiveModel::Validations` module. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html

Comment: i mean in the `MyValidator` class! i tried declaring a @record, and then defining a `validates_presence_of @record[:Id]` and in the validate method i did `@record = record` but i get a Nil error for the `[ ]` accessor...